# Nhibernate mapping between tables that have a intermediate table in between

Tags: c#, nhibernate, mapping

I have the following code:

```
public class Hotel
{
  public int ID
  {  
    get;set
  } 

  public IList<Photo> Photos
  {
    get;set;
  }
  //...other code
}

public class Photo
{
  public int ID
  {
     get;set;
  }
  //...other fields
}
```

In the database, I have the following tables:

```
Photo: ID, Url, //.. other fields
HotelPhoto:ID, PhotoID, HotelID
Hotel:ID, Location, //..other fields
```

with relationships between `Hotel <--> HotelPhoto` and `HotelPhoto <--> Photo`.

My question is: Can I configure somehow a mapping between `Hotel` class and `Hotel` table  to get a list of `Photo` without creating a new class `HotelPhoto`? ( I want a list of photos, not a list of HotelPhoto from which to get my photos).

Somehow I want to access the Photo table from the Hotel class without any class HotelPhoto, knowing that the table HotelPhoto contains only the IDs of Hotel and Photo table.

Thanks in advance,
Tamash

Comment: How can a Photo belong to more than 1 Hotel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `many-to-many`-mapping e.g.:

The hotel mapping file, should contain sth. like this:

```
<set name="Photos" table="HotelPhoto">
  <key column="HotelId" />
  <many-to-many class="Photo" column="PhotoId"/>
</set>
```

For the photo mapping file you can use sth. like this:

```
<set name="Hotels" table="HotelPhoto">
  <key column="PhotoId" />
  <many-to-many class="Hotel" column="HotelId"/>
</set>
```

Note, that the mapping is not tested and assumes that a Photo has a list of hotels (otherwise your db-schema does not make sense for me).

You can find the documentation here. http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#collections-ofvalues

Comment: Well I only need the first part. The Photo does not has a list of hotels since it is beeing reused for other objects as well (for instance a Restaurant may have also a RestaurantPhoto table containing the IDs of Photo and Hotel tables). I dont want in my Photo table to have a HotelID, RestaurantID, a.s.o. foreign keys.